# Extract row indices where duplicated pairs exist and the values of these rows which are different

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
master <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), B=c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8),C=c(5,2,5,7,7,5,7,9,7,8),D=c(1,2,5,3,7,5,9,6,7,0))
```

As you can see I have 4 columns `A,B,C,D`. What I want to achieve is to create a new dataframe which will include the duplicated pair-rows between `A` and `B`, the index of rows where this duplication happens and the column names that make those rows different (`C,D`,or `C` and `D`) in a third column. To make my request more clear I display an example with `master2` instead of `master` which includes only `A` and `B`

```
master2 <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), B=c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8))
```

and then with:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(master2)

master2[master2[, .N, by=names(master2)][ N > 1L ], on=names(master2), 
  .(N, locs = .(.I)), by=.EACHI]
```

I get:

```
#    A B N locs
# 1: 2 3 2  3,4
# 2: 4 6 2  7,8
```

So I want this logic implemented to the `master` dataframe and also add another column named "Different" with the column names that make those rows different. If the rows are identical to everything then the new column with the column names that differ should take as value "nothing".If it is possible to add another column with the initial position of the "Different"column. It will be 3 for C and 4 for D?

The desired output shpuld be something like:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   A [?]
#     A     B     n locs  different position
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr> <chr>    <int>
#1     2     3     2 3, 4  C, D     3,4
#2     4     6     2 7, 8  C, D     3,4
```

Comment: Why is it 3, 4 for 2nd row?

Comment: because it is different by C and D which are in the 3rd and 4th position of the master dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the row index, then create a sequence column ('rn'), grouped by the columns of interest, keep only groups that have number of rows greater than 1, `summarise` to get the number of rows (`n()`) as well as the `paste`ed index of the sequence of rows for the group.  Regarding the 'different' column, it is not entirely clear about the logic.  Here, is one implemented based on the occurrence of different values within the same group of 'A' and 'B' with `case_when`

```
library(tidyverse)
master %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   group_by(A, B) %>% 
   filter(n() > 1) %>% 
   summarise(n = n(), 
            locs =  toString(rn),
            Different = case_when(n_distinct(C) > 1 & n_distinct(D) > 1 ~ 'C, D', 
                                  n_distinct(C) > 1 ~ 'C', 
                                  n_distinct(D) > 1 ~ 'D', 
                                  TRUE ~ 'Same')) 
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   A [?]
#     A     B     n locs  different
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr> <chr>    
#1     2     3     2 3, 4  C, D     
#2     4     6     2 7, 8  C, D
```

#### Update

Based on the comments to include 'position'

```
master %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    group_by(A, B) %>% 
    filter(n() > 1) %>% 
    mutate(position = toString(rn[!(duplicated(paste(C, D))| 
              duplicated(paste(C, D), fromLast = TRUE))])) %>%
    summarise(n = n(), 
             locs =  toString(rn),
             Different = case_when(n_distinct(C) > 1 & n_distinct(D) > 1 ~ 'C, D', 
                                   n_distinct(C) > 1 ~ 'C', 
                                   n_distinct(D) > 1 ~ 'D', 
                                   TRUE ~ 'Same'),
             position = first(position))
```

Comment: great answer tnx!

Comment: is it possible to add another column with the initial position of the "Different"column. It will be 3 for C and 4 for D?

Comment: In this case, it is the same as `locs`.  With a different example, it may become more clear about the intended output

Comment: Now the position is same as the locs but in this case I want the column position. Do u want me to create a new Q since the  original is answered?

Comment: @firmo23  It would be better to create a new question.